# Compilation warning when instantiating template function

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why the compilation note is generated for this code? The error occurs when compiling in `typename T::value_type e`.  I checked and `value_type` exists in vector header `typedef _Tp value_type;`  Thanks

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void f(T& c)
{
    typename T::value_type e = c[0];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v = {0, 1};
    f(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall test181.cc && ./a.out
test181.cc:7:28: warning: unused variable 'e' [-Wunused-variable]
    typename T::value_type e = c[0];
                           ^
test181.cc:13:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'f<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' requested here
    f(v);
    ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: It's a warning...

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica it has "note" prefixed.

Comment: The note pertains to the warning...

Comment: The warning is quite self explanatory, isn't it?

Comment: I have already posted an answer, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's letting you know that you've written to a variable that never gets read, which is usually a code smell. As mentioned in the comments, this is only a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

The note was really pertaining to a warning of an unused variable.  Use the variable to get rid of the warning.